# How to render blaze-svg markup within blaze-html

Tags: html, haskell, svg, blaze-html

I want to include a svg diagram generated with blaze-svg directly in html generated with blaze-html. Both are based on blaze-markup, so I expected it to be easy.

```
diagram1 :: Svg
diagram1 = ... 

try1 :: Html
try1 = html $
  body $ do
    h1 "My first diagram"
    toHtml diagram1

try2 :: Html
try2 :: html $
  body $ do
    h1 "My first diagram"
    toHtml $ renderSvg diagram1
```

Both try1 and try2 passes the compiler but neither shows the diagram. What is the right way? Is it a problem with including the svg tag directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try2` first generates a string representation of the SVG with `renderSvg`, escapes it (`toHtml`) and includes the result into the HTML output. Using it, you should see the source of the SVG instead of the resulting image.

`try1` should actually work. `toHtml` is defined as the identity on the `Svg` type, so you could also just use `diagram1` directly.

Here is a complete example that generates a HTML document with embedded SVG:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (head)
import Text.Blaze.Svg11 hiding (title)
import Text.Blaze.Svg11.Attributes hiding (title)
import Text.Blaze.Html5
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Pretty

diagram1 :: Svg
diagram1 = svg ! width "100" ! height "100" $
  circle ! cx "50" ! cy "50" ! r "40" ! stroke "green"
         ! strokeWidth "4" ! fill "yellow"

try2 :: Html
try2 = docTypeHtml $ do
  head $ title "Works"
  body $ do
    h1 "My first diagram"
    diagram1

main :: IO ()
main = putStr $ renderHtml try2
```

Comment: I was using the above packages to generate emails sent with ses-html (relies on blaze-html) and with Chart + Chart-diagrams. The problem is that Gmail does not support SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example from the `blaze-svg` package modified to be embedded in an HTML document:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.Blaze.Svg11 ((!), mkPath, rotate, l, m)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Svg11 as S
import qualified Text.Blaze.Svg11.Attributes as A
import Text.Blaze.Svg.Renderer.String (renderSvg)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5 as H
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TL

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = renderHtml try1 -- renderSvg svgDoc
  TL.putStrLn a

try1 :: H.Html
try1 = H.html $
  H.body $ do
    H.h1 "My first diagram"
    svgDoc

-- svgDoc :: S.Svg
svgDoc = S.svg ! A.version "1.1" ! A.width "150" ! A.height "100" ! A.viewbox "0 0 3 2" $ do
    S.g ! A.transform makeTransform $ do
      S.rect ! A.width "1" ! A.height "2" ! A.fill "#008d46"
      S.rect ! A.width "1" ! A.height "2" ! A.fill "#ffffff"
      S.rect ! A.width "1" ! A.height "2" ! A.fill "#d2232c"
      S.path ! A.d makePath

makePath :: S.AttributeValue
makePath = mkPath $ do
  l 2 3
  m 4 5

makeTransform :: S.AttributeValue
makeTransform = rotate 50
```