# How do I use svg-builder Elements in blaze-html?

Tags: haskell, svg, blaze-html

I'm using [svg-builder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/svg-builder) to create
some simple drawings eg

```
import Graphics.Svg

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ svg contents

svg :: Element -> Element
svg content =
    doctype
    <> with (svg11_ content) [Version_ <<- "1.1", Width_ <<- "300", Height_ <<- "200"]

contents :: Element
contents =
    circle_ [Cx_ <<- "50", Cy_ <<- "50", R_ <<-"40", Stroke_ <<- "green", Stroke_width_ <<- "4", Fill_ <<- "yellow" ]
```

Now I want to embed such drawings into a normal Html page, eg constructed with
[blaze-html](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html).
The difficulty is, that `blaze-html` uses data types like `Html` and `Builder`, however
`svg-builder` uses a data type called `Element`.
How can I use `svg-builder` `Element`s in `blaze-html`?

Note : There is [this similar so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175106/how-to-render-blaze-svg-markup-within-blaze-html)
but it uses `blaze-svg` and I would like to use `svg-builder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`renderText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/svg-builder-0.1.1/docs/Graphics-Svg-Core.html#v:renderText) from `svg-builder`, pass the resulting text into [`preEscapedToHtml`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.9.1.2/docs/Text-Blaze-Html.html#v:preEscapedToHtml) from `blaze-html`. Note that you do *not* want to include the doctype here.